# Can someone help me understand this Jorja Smith song?

Tags: beginner

I'm a beginner as far as music theory goes however would like to know more about this song. I notice that the piano is changing keys constantly but it still sounds good. Does this have something to do with modes and if so what mode is she playing in? Would also appreciate some beginner readings/piano pieces.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a beginner as far as music theory goes however would like to know
>   more about this song.

When you study first information about chords you would know and understand a lot more about this song. It is always motivating to everybody if **first** there are questions about chords and **then** you read about chord building.

> I notice that the piano is changing keys constantly but it still
>   sounds good.

In almost all piano pieces the chords change (not the key):

> Does this have something to do with modes and if so what mode is she playing in?

some chords are just borrowed from other keys as substitution for the mode chords he is playing in. I could write you down the chords but this is not the purpose of this site.
There are keyboards that show the chords on a display on the desk.

you might also look up for a midi file and load down a midi player that analyzes the chords.

> Would also appreciate some beginner readings/piano pieces.

While I'm writing this answer youtube is playing some more examples  of  Jorja Smith Piano Tutorial:

they would all fit or benefit for a beginner! as you like this style you should try to write down the sheet music, so you will achieve the ability of reading:

**!READING BY WRITING!**

and you will understand better the chords and the explications about the theory of the chords.